# SQL Count NULL values is 0 even when there are NULL values

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, sql-null

In a particular case I have a database table populated with 1070 items, and at some point in the process I add a column called 'Current_Status' to it. As a result, all items have a new field that is initially *NULL*.

This table is used as a queue, and for each row that is processed, I update the 'Current_Status' field to 'Processed' or 'Non processed'.

In order to see how is the process going, I was counting the remaining items that still had the status *NULL* using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT([Current_Status]) FROM Table_Name WHERE [Current_Status] IS NULL
```

The issue is that after the first 1000 items, the result for that query execution was `0`, even if I checked and using a `SELECT * FROM Table_Name` query shown that there where still some rows with status *NULL*.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

I checked this situation using Azure Data Studio 1.4.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for that is because you have provided count with a column value which is `null`. Instead, use `count(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table_Name WHERE [Current_Status] IS NULL
```

---

Sample data:

```
current_status
--------------
Processed
Null
Not Processed
Null
```

And the difference between two queries:

**count(current_status)**

```
SELECT count(current_status) FROM table_name WHERE current_status IS NULL 

0
```

**count(*)**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE current_status IS NULL 

2
```

Comment: But the problem is coming up when there are values in the column distinct than null (almost all of them). Using '*' instead would solve the issue then?

Answer (score 4):

With

```
SELECT COUNT([Current_Status]) FROM Table_Name WHERE [Current_Status] IS NULL
```

you say "take all rows where the `current_status` is null and count how many of these `current_status` are not null". Which is zero of course. `COUNT(<expression>)` counts non-null occurrences of the expression.

You want to count rows instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE current_status IS NULL;
```

Or count remains:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(current_status) FROM table_name;
```